# Run a script from every directory on ubuntu linux

Tags: bash, scripts

I am new to Linux. On my Desktop, I have created the following script called trimmomatic

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar /home/aishah/software_library/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar
```

When I open a terminal and do

```
$ cd Desktop
```

followed by

```
$ bash trimmomatic
```

the script works.

However, the script does not work if I run it starting from directories other than `Desktop`. For example, when I open a terminal and directly do

```
$ bash trimmomatic
```

it says

```
bash: trimmomatic: No such file or directory
```

What can I do to be able to run the script from any directory?

Please give me detailed instructions of all commands to type and where to type.

Answer (score 3):

There's couple things you need to keep in mind:

1. `bash` accepts a script file as argument, which is what `bash trimmomatic` does, however `bash trimmomatic` implies that the file `trimmomatic` has to be in the current working directory where you execute the command `bash trimmomatic`. Command-line parameters which are files, unless specified with full path, have to be in current working directory.
2. When you execute any non-builtin command in shell, such as `ls` or `df`, the shell goes through list of directories in `$PATH` variable.  If a file is found and is executable in any of those directories, then the shell will execute it. Of course, `~/Desktop` is not on the list of directories in `$PATH`, so you cannot call it directly as `trimmomatic`

Now, you have a single-line script. Practically speaking, a full script is unnecessary in case where you have just a single command there, unless it is intended to be shared with other users on the system. A far more practical way, would be to define an alias or a function in your `~/.bashrc` file. For a function, you can do

```
trimmomatic(){
    java -jar /home/aishah/software_library/Trimmomatic-0.36/trimmomatic-0.36.jar
}
```

After you append this to `~/.bashrc`, run `source ~/.bashrc` command, and the function can be called as

```
$ trimmomatic
```

Functions don't depend on `$PATH`, hence you can execute them anywhere.  If you do insist on using a script, then I would suggest placing the script into `~/bin` directory or `~/.local/bin`. On Ubuntu `~/bin` is added to `$PATH` when you sign in through `~/.profile` config file, however `~/.local/bin`  is not, so you would have to add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file: `PATH="$PATH:~/.local/bin`. In both cases remember to source config file to update your current shell environment. Once that is done, the shell will start looking in either of those directories, and if your script is located there, it will be executed. Of course, this way you don't need to call the script via `bash trimmomatic`, rather you can call `trimmomatic` directly.

Comment: How is the following done?                                                                                   source config file to update your current shell environment

Comment: @user796294 Use command `source ~/.bashrc`. If you update that file, changes won't affect the shell unless you run that command

Answer (score 0):

Put the script in /usr/bin or in /bin and give it execution permission.
Doing like this you should be able to execute the script from anywhere.